# Loss of Significance problems - Taylor Expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

(2) This question addresses the notion of loss of signiﬁcance. You are encouraged to revisit the
Taylor series expansion that you have learned in calculus, as you will need to apply it here.
Explain why in each of the following expressions a loss of signiﬁcance may occur and rearrange
each of them to avoid it.

$$
\begin{align}
(a) & \frac{x^4-y^4}{x^3-y^3}, \text{ near } x = y = 3. \\
(b) & \sin x − \cos x, \text{ near } x = \frac{\pi}{4}. \\
(c) & e^{2y}-e^{-y}, \text{ near } y = 0.
\end{align}
$$

I've been working on this problem for a while and can't seem to come up with a way to do it.  If you could point me to some kind of tutorial for Taylor series and loss of significance that would be great.

Comment: The Taylor series is of significance mainly for the third problem. Let $y$ be very close to $0$. Then $e^{2y}\approx 1+2y+\frac{(2y)^2}{2!}+\cdots$ (we may want more terms, probably not). Similarly, $e^{-y}\approx 1-y+\frac{y^2}{2!}-\cdots$. Note that each term begins with a $1$. If $|y|$ is very very close to $0$, like $10^{-12}$, the $1$ swamps the rest of the terms, and subtraction leads to catastrophic loss of significance. But if we subtract the series, we get $\approx 3y+\frac{3y^2}{2!}$, an excellent approximation.